# IF formula to let value stay to its initial value when FALSE

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets

I have this table on my spreadsheet:

```
STATUS      END DATE
 WIP       10/07/2099
```

I would like to make STATUS column to:

- value "LATE" when today() > END DATE, or
- value current value ("WIP" in this sample) when today()<= END DATE

I tried this one, which is obviously stupid

```
=if(today()> END DATE ,"LATE", STATUS)
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Which cells are this data or table in?  Is this your first time using Excel?  Stack Overflow is for **programming questions**. Unless there's something you're not mentioning, this is one of the most simple things to do in Excel,  Don't refer to the column names, refer to the location of the data.  Check Google for a beginner's Excel tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Technically if the formula is going in A2 and the date is in B2 then `=IF(TODAY() > B2,"LATE","WIP")` should work, but you will have to modify your formula every time the project status changes. What you probably want is a 3rd column that tracks the state of the work on the project so you would have something more like `=IF(TODAY() > B2,"LATE",C2)` assuming the work status goes in C2